# When a record is inserted in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I got a task to do, but I don't know exactly how to do it.
I need a Stored Procedure to run every 5 min and validate if a new record has been inserted in one table. If new record is found then execute an insert into another table to make a copy of that record, but if not, then nothing happens and both tables remain the same.
In other words, I need something similar to "after insert" trigger, but I don't want to use a trigger.

Comment: How can you identify the new record? Why don't you want to use a trigger? It's very much what they are for

Comment: @emancia Why not use a Transaction that will insert a new row (copy row) in your second table,Since you didnt provided much details so my suggestion also lacks your business logic implementations and your requirements.

Comment: You mean [replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Comment: I agree with @Elliveny - Triggers are what you want, not cron jobs running stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

Create the stored procedure that you want to run, and then install it as a scheduled job within sql server that runs every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Do what jhilden suggests with the SQL job running every 5 minutes.
The SP needs to look at the latest record in the copy of the table (timestamp or MAX(ID) if you are conserving the IDs accross the two tables) then check if there is/are a record(s) in the original table with a higher timestamp (or ID), if so copy it/them accross.